# Iterate over Object

Tags: java, arrays, object

I have an object `o` which I know for fact that it is an array of something.
How do I iterate over `ȯ`?

```
Object o;
if (o != null && o.getClass().isArray()) {
  for (Object each : o) {  // compile error, of course
    System.out.println(each);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have cast that object to array before iterate through it.

```
if (o != null && o.getClass().isArray()) {
  Object[] temp (Object[] o)
  for (Object each : temp) {  
    System.out.println(each);
  }
}
```

Comment: Pretty obvious. I just though it would throw ClassCastException when it is a String[] or something else.

Answer (score 3):

cast it to an array, like this:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    Object o = new Object[]{"one", "two"};
    if (o != null && o.getClass().isArray()) {
        for (Object each : (Object[])o) {  // no compile error, of course
            System.out.println(each);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This would work, indeed. Won't argue with that. However, casting should be avoided in general. If you're so certain that the 'object' is in-fact an Array make it explicit in your code!

The premise is that you must be able to alter the code that produces the Array..

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
ArrayList<Array_Type> array= (ArrayList<Array_Type>) o;
Iterator iterator=array.iterator();
System.out.println(iterator.next());
```

Java have [Iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) interface that can walk through an `Collection`, so if your 'o' Object is an array, cast it into 'array' `ArrayList` and iterate on it.

Comment: [Please have a look at this thread.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/250872/1686291)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
Object o = null;
Iterator ite = ((Iterable)o).iterator();
while(ite.hasNext()){
     Object itObj = ite.next();
}
```